How to create a loop of different series ID to automatically download data using API from FRED?
This is the first time I'm trying Python. It's for university work and I am required to download all transaction house price index from all counties. (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/searchresults/?st=all%20transaction%20house%20price%20index&t=county&ob=sr&od=desc)
I have the FIPS codes for different counties from another file and so I am writing the code to use these codes to generate series ID and use my API key to retrieve the data for all series ID in a loop.
But it returns the error for a lot of these codes stating:
"Error fetching data for county_id ATNHPIUS01095A: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
Can anyone please help?

import pandas as pd
import requests
df = pd.read_stata(r"D:\Entertaintment\Uni\Seminar Behavioural Finance\Group Assignment\unemployment 12-17.dta")
df = df[['FIPS']]
df['county_id'] = 'ATNHPIUS' + df['FIPS'].astype(str) + 'A'
county_ids = df['county_id'].unique()
print (df.head())
def fetch_data(county_id):
    api_key = "mykey"
    url = f'https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id={county_id}&api_key={api_key}'
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        observations = data['observations']
        df = pd.DataFrame(observations)
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
        df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
        df.rename(columns={'value': county_id}, inplace=True)
        return df
    else:
            print(f"No observations found for county_id {county_id}")
            return None
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data for county_id {county_id}: {e}")
        return None  # Return None if data fetching fails for a county_id

dataframes = []
for county_id in county_ids:
   data_df = fetch_data(county_ids)
   if data_df is not None:
       dataframes.append(data_df)
       
combined_df = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
print(combined_df.head())


What is different between the ones that work and the ones that don't?

You need to look closely at the URL that you generate for the ones that fail, and compare it to a valid URL that works through a browser.

what are the contents of the file in the df.read_stata() method ?
